# $E[U^2]=0$ implies $Pr(U=0)=1$

Tags: statistics

DeGroot starts the proof to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with the assumption that $U$ and $V$ are random variables such that $E[UV]$ exists, then starts the proof with the following statement:

If $E(U^2) = 0$, then $Pr(U = 0) = 1$. Therefore, it must also be true that $Pr(UV = 0) = 1$. Hence, $E(UV ) = 0$.

1. How do I show that $E(U^2)=0$ implies $Pr(U=0)=1$?
2. How do I then show that $Pr(UV=0)=1$?
3. And finally, how do I show that $E[UV]=0$?

Comment: For (2), $Pr(UV=0)=Pr(U=0\lor V=0)\leq Pr(U=0)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\le$ in the sense of $\ge$.

Answer (score 2):

1) Since $U^2 \geq 0$, we have $E(U^2) = 0$ iff $U^2 = 0$ almost surely; that is, iff $U = 0$ almost surely. More formally, if $P(U = 0) < 1$, then there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that the event $\omega = \{|U|\geq \epsilon\}$ has $P(\omega) > 0$. Thus
$$E[U^2] \geq P(\omega)\; E[U^2\;\Big|\;\omega] \geq \epsilon^2 P(\omega) > 0,$$
a contradiction.

2) Since $P(U = 0) = 1$, we have $P(UV = 0) = P(UV = 0\;|\; U = 0) = 1$.

3) Since $UV = 0$ with probability $1$, it follows immediately that $E[UV] = 0$.